# Datepicker block selection of days, not disabling

Tags: javascript

Hi I have datepicker that i modify. I have a select range, days are available and not available, which the color changes depending the state. I use the functions beforeshowday and onSelect to do this and till here works excelent.

My problem comes that now I want to disable the selection of anyday, I mean I just want to show the user the days availables and not availables, the user can move trough the months and years, but he should not be able to click in a day.

I cant disable the day, I can't return false, this is not a solution, otherwise available days would look like not available.

This example is not mine but is similar, as you can see days not available have opacity, the days available are full color, so without lose this view, I want to not allow the user to click on any day available, but yes move between months and years clicking on the arrows.

http://jsfiddle.net/kVsbq/4/

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    },
    beforeShowDay: function (d) {
        var dmy = (d.getMonth() + 1);
        if (d.getMonth() < 9)
            dmy = "0" + dmy;
        dmy += "-";
        if (d.getDate() < 10) dmy += "0";
        dmy += d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear();
        console.log(dmy + ' : ' + ($.inArray(dmy, notAvailableDates)));
        if ($.inArray(dmy, notAvailableDates) != -1) {
            return [false, "", "Booked"];
        } else {
            return [true, "", "Book Now"];
        }
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    },
    beforeShowDay: function (d) {
        var dmy = (d.getMonth() + 1);
        if (d.getMonth() < 9)
            dmy = "0" + dmy;
        dmy += "-";
        if (d.getDate() < 10) dmy += "0";
        dmy += d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear();
        console.log(dmy + ' : ' + ($.inArray(dmy, notAvailableDates)));
        if ($.inArray(dmy, notAvailableDates) != -1) {
            return [false, "", "Booked"];
        } else {
            return [true, "", "Book Now"];
        }
    }
});
```